# How would I randomly select 10 elements of a Numpy array from each row, and plot using plt.matshow()?

Tags: python, database, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I have been searching for a solution for days now and I can't seem to find the solution.

I have two datasets, X and Y, X is (3000,784), and Y is (3000, 1) a binary class dataset.

How would I randomly select 10 elements from each row of X, and construct a new matrix from this, that I could plot against Y using plt.matshow()?

I have tried using np.apply_along_axis() however I cant seem to get it right.

```
   def random_indices(Xtrain, Counts):
       indices = np.random.choice(Xtrain[0,:], Counts, replace=False)
       return indices
Counts = 10

random_indices(Xtrain, Counts)
```

This is my function that retrieves random numbers from the first row, however I have tried looping this over all rows, and tried using this in np.apply_along_axis however it seems to fail

Answer (score 0):

Your data is pretty small, I think you can try loop:

```
def row_sample(X, count):
    return np.array([np.random.choice(row, count, replace=False) for row in X])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, how would I do this? Would it be possible to then create a new matrix from the results?

Comment: Yes the code should return a 2D array which you can use with plt.matshow

Comment: It does return a 2D array, however it plots as a 1D graph for some reason? I can attach a png if you would like, but im not sure how to solve this